# Select option in a html popup is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have inherited an application, which is based on Semantic and Wordpress. The thing is that, I need to have a drop sown shown in a pop up, where in depending on the value chosen, the application will do something. I am stuck at the point where the selected option is supposed to be picked up, but only the first option is getting picked up.

What am I doing wrong? (I inherited this code and any major changes will take time to implement).

```
$('.showSomething').on('click', showSomething);
function showSomething () {
    var message = 
    '<div id="selectMe" class="ui long modal" style="display: block !important;width:450px !important;height:180px;color:black; position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;">' + '\n' +
        '<h4 style = "position: absolute; top:5%; left:30% ; right: 30%;text-align:center;">Something</h4>' + 
        '<select style = "position: absolute; top:35%; left:40% ; right: 30%;text-align:center;">' +
            '<option selected value="">Select Product ID Type</option>' +
            '<option value="option1">option1</option>' +
            '<option value="option2">option2</option>' +
            '<option value="option3">option3</option>' +
            '<option value="option4">option4</option>' +
        '</select>' +
    '<div class="actions" style="overflow:hidden">' + '\n' +
        '<div class="ui approve primary button" style="height: 36px;position: absolute; bottom:10%; left:20% ; right: 55%;text-align:center;">OK</div>' + '\n' +
        '<div class="ui cancel primary button" style="height: 36px;position: absolute; bottom:10%; left:50% ; right: 20%;text-align:center;"  >Cancel</div>' + '\n' +
    '</div>' + '\n' +
    '</div>';       
    var toShow = '<html><div style="position: absolute; background:grey; top: 20px !important; position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0">' + message + '</div></html>';
    
    $('.tiny.modal .content').html(toShow).modal({
        closable: false,
        onDeny: function() {
            location.reload();
        },
        onApprove: function() {
            alert( "Selected option:" + $( "#selectMe option:selected" ).text() );
            location.reload();
        },
        dimmerSettings: {
            opacity: 0
        }
    }).modal('show');               
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6jv7sohu/2/

How to I get the correct selection in console.log statement?

Comment: can u update your fiddle or create a new fiddle ? shared fiddle doesn't have JS code

Comment: What is `$('.showSomething')`? You haven't shared all the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Pl reload the fiddle link.

Comment: Hi , your selectbox box doesn't have id `selectMe`.

Comment: Good point. However, if you would have tried that .. you would have noticed that does not work either. Already tried that .. thats why I know :)

Comment: can you make this runnable ?